# Convolution to regularize list

Tags: list-manipulation, convolution

I try to regularize a given list of points, say `f=Table[Exp[-a t],{t,0,100}]`, with some kernel

$h_{\sigma}(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma}}e^{-\frac{t^2}{2\sigma ^2}}$, so that I get function $$g_\sigma (t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dt' h_{\sigma}(t-t')f(t').$$
However I unfortunately do not see how `Convole` or `ListConvolve` work for me because I neither have two lists nor two analytic functions. (Here `f` is just an example)

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: or is simply `g[t]=Sum[hsigma[t-t']*f[t'],{t',0,Length@f}]` the best solution?

Comment: You'll need to create a discrete list from your `h[t]` for a given `sigma` value. Then `ListConvolve will handle it.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau doing so yields again a list. I am however interested in an analytic expression for the regularization.

Answer (score 3):

If you want ContinuousTimeConvolution, here is the answer:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
h[\[Sigma]_] := 
  1/Sqrt[2 Pi*\[Sigma]]*Exp[-Superscript[t, "'"]^2/(2 \[Sigma]^2)];
f = Exp[-a*Superscript[t, "'"]]*
    HeavisideTheta[Superscript[t, "'"] - 0] + 
   Exp[-a*Superscript[t, "'"]]*
    HeavisideTheta[-Superscript[t, "'"] + 100];
Convolve[h[\[Sigma]], f, Superscript[t, "'"], t]
% // FullSimplify // Expand
```

$$
\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\sigma } e^{\frac{1}{2} a \left(a \sigma ^2-2 t\right)} \text{erf}\left(\frac{a \sigma ^2-t+100}{\sqrt{2} \sigma }\right)+\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\sigma } e^{\frac{1}{2} a \left(a \sigma ^2-2 t\right)} \text{erf}\left(\frac{t-a \sigma ^2}{\sqrt{2} \sigma }\right)+\sqrt{\frac{1}{\sigma ^2}} \sigma ^{3/2} e^{\frac{1}{2} a \left(a \sigma ^2-2 t\right)}
$$

---

If you want LinearConvolution (like Polynomial Multiplication) of 2 lists, you should use `Sum`

```
(*It takes too long time to get the result, DON'T RUN THE CODE!!! *)


Clear["Global`*"];
yourSamplingPeriod = 1;
h[\[Sigma]_] := 
  1/Sqrt[2 Pi*\[Sigma]]*Exp[-Superscript[t, "'"]^2/(2 \[Sigma]^2)];
h[\[Sigma]_, n_] := h[\[Sigma]] /. {t -> n*yourSamplingPeriod};
f[n_] := Table[Exp[-a t], {t, 0, 100}];
Sum[h[\[Sigma], Superscript[n, "'"]]*
  f[n - Superscript[n, "'"]], {Superscript[n, "'"], -Infinity, 
  Infinity}]
```

---

If you want LinearConvolution (like Polynomial Multiplication) of 2 length-limited lists, you should use `ListConvolve[lst1, lst2, {1, -1}, 0]`

```
Clear["Global`*"];
ListConvolve[{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}, {1, -1}, 0]
```

$$
\{a d,a e+b d,a f+b e+c d,b f+c e,c f\}
$$

here $h(t)$ is time-continuous, you should do windowing then sampling (or do sampling then windowing???), convert it to a length-limited list $h(n)$, then make LinearConvolution with your length-limited list $f(n)$

```
Clear["Global`*"];
yourSamplingPeriod = 1;
h[\[Sigma]_] := 
  1/Sqrt[2 Pi*\[Sigma]]*Exp[-Superscript[t, "'"]^2/(2 \[Sigma]^2)];
h[\[Sigma]_, n_] := h[\[Sigma]] /. {t -> n*yourSamplingPeriod};
hLength201 = Table[h[\[Sigma], n], {n, -100, 100}];
w = Array[BlackmanWindow, Length@hLength201, {-1/2, 1/2}];
hAddWindowing = hLength201*w;
f = Table[Exp[-a t], {t, 0, 100}];
ListConvolve[hAddWindowing, f, {1, -1}, 0];
% // Take[#, 5] &
```

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer. However I am interested in a continuous convolution of a list and a function. Therefore the first part of your answer assumes that you have an analytic form of the list ```f``` of my example. Crucially I am interested in cases where you only have a list (not knowing the function it arises from).